# php - the while statement including a "if" condition is block with the first item from the database and doesn't increment

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I am using 3 tables (`Region`, `Country`, `Market Strategy`). 
I have the function php `marketStrategyT` and `strategyExists`.

The function php `marketStrategyT` get all the statements for the drop-down menu.
The function php `strategyExists` check if we do have a market strategy either in the selected region, or in the selected country.

**Here is the problem**

The drop-down menu doesn't display the list of market strategy per region and per country. Nothing is displayed. 
With some echo, I can see the first region and the first country are taken by the function marketStrategyT, show the correct information with the function strategyExists. Nothing is displayed because the first country (America - Argentina) doens't have any market strategy. However, the while doesn't look at the remaining country/region.

**Here is what the function `marketStrategyT` should do**

(1) Getting all the Region from the database `Region`.
(2) Using the function `strategyExists` in order to see if we have a market strategy in this specific region.

- function strategyExists return `FALSE` => we don't have a market strategy in this region (go to point 1)
- function strategyExists return `TRUE` => we have a market strategy in this region (go to point 3)

(3) Getting all the Country from the database `Country`.
(4) Using the function `strategy Exists` in order to see if we have a market strategy in this specific country

- function strategyExists return `FALSE` => we don't have a market strategy in this country (go to point 3).
- function strategyExists return `TRUE` => we have a market strategy in  this country (go to point 5).

(5) Display the name of the market strategy for the drop down list.

**Here the code php**

```
// LIST OF MARKET STRATEGY AVEC COUNTRY
 function marketStrategyT(){
    $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=workplan; charset=utf8', 'root','');
    $marketStrategy_return=array();
    // To select all regions
    $region=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM region ORDER BY region");
    // ==> (1) <==
    while($data_region=$region->fetch()){
        // Definition of variables
        $region_id=$data_region['region_id'];
        $region=$data_region['region'];
        // checking if there is any strategy for this region
        // ==> (2) <==
        $regionStrategyExists=strategyExists($region_id, 'region'); // should return 'true' or 'false'
        if ($regionStrategyExists) {
            // To display the name of the region in the drop-down menu
            $marketStrategy_return[]="<option value=\"N/A\">" . $region . "</option>\n";
            // To select all countries
            $country=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_region_id='". $region_id ."' ORDER BY country");
            // ==> (3) <==
            while($data_country=$country->fetch()){
                // Definition of variables
                $country_id=$data_country['country_id'];
                $country=$data_country['country'];
                // checking if there is any strategy for this region
                // ==> (4) <==
                $countryStrategyExists=strategyExists($country_id, 'country');// should return 'true' or 'false'
                if ($countryStrategyExists) {
                    // To display the name of the country in the drop-down menu
                    $marketStrategy_return[]="<option value=\"N/A\">" . $country . "</option>\n";
                    // To select all strategy
                    $strategy=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM market_strategy WHERE region_id='" . $region_id."' AND country_id='".$country_id."' ORDER BY name");
                    // ==> (5) <==
                    while($data_strategy=$strategy->fetch()){
                        // Definition of variables
                        $market_strategy_id=$data_strategy['market_strategy_id'];
                        $market_strategy=$data_strategy['name'];

                        // inserting the name of the strategy
                        $marketStrategy_return[]="<option value=\"" . $market_strategy_id . "\">" . $market_strategy . "</option>\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return $marketStrategy_return;
}
```

**function strategyExists**

```
// STRATEGY EXISTS
 function strategyExists($val, $type){
    $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=workplan; charset=utf8', 'root','');
    // $val represent the id
    // $type represent the table (region / country)
    // Default value is False -> there is no strategy for this region / this country
    $return=False;
    // Checking if there is any strategy for the region
    if ($type == 'region') {
        $strategy=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM market_strategy WHERE region_id='".$val."' ORDER BY name");
        while($data=$strategy->fetch()) {
            $return=True;
        }
    } elseif($type == 'country') { // Checking if there is any strategy for the country
        $strategy=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM market_strategy WHERE country_id='".$val."' ORDER BY name");
        while($data=$strategy->fetch()) {
            $return=True;
        }

    }
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're reusing the variable `$region`. This is initially set with:

```
$region=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM region ORDER BY region");
```

So it contains the result of the query. You're using this in the `while` condition:

```
while($data_region=$region->fetch()){
```

But inside the loop you do:

```
$region=$data_region['region'];
```

So the next time the loop condition is executed `$region->fetch()` gets an error because `$region` no longer contains the query result.

Use a different variable inside the loop, e.g.

```
$region_name = $data_region['region'];
```

and later:

```
$marketStrategy_return[]="<option value=\"N/A\">" . $region_name . "</option>\n";
```

Also, you don't need `while` loops in `strategyExists`. Change the queries to return a single row with `LIMIT 1`, and then just test if the `fetch()` succeeds. And you should use prepared statements rather than substituting variables directly into the SQL.

```
// STRATEGY EXISTS
function strategyExists($val, $type){
    $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=workplan; charset=utf8', 'root','');
    // $val represent the id
    // $type represent the table (region / country)
    // Default value is False -> there is no strategy for this region / this country
    $return=False;
    // Checking if there is any strategy for the region
    if ($type == 'region') {
        $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM market_strategy WHERE region_id= :value LIMIT 1";
    } elseif ($type = 'country') {
        $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM market_strategy WHERE country_id= :value LIMIT 1";
    } else {
        die("Invalid type $type");
    }
    $stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":value", $val);
    $strategy = $stmt->execute();
    if ($strategy->fetch()) {
        $return = true;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. And indeed, using LIMIT 1 is more efficient. thnks.

Answer (score 1):

The logic as below from `strategyExists()` may not be ideal.

```
if ($type == 'region') {
    $strategy=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM market_strategy WHERE region_id='".$val."' ORDER BY name");
    while($data=$strategy->fetch()) {
        $return=True;
    }
```

1. $strategy_fetch() uses the default parameter PDO::FETCH_BOTH ie its the same as $strategy_fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) which either returns an array or False. So its not clear what will be result of a logical test on the return value.
2. You should not need to load the full result set to see if there are any rows. its better to use `count(*)` which returns the number of rows, or just `TOP 1` to find the first row.

I don't know if this will solve all the problems, but you should first clean up the code in `strategyExists()` as per below.

```
// STRATEGY EXISTS
 function strategyExists($val, $type){
    $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=workplan; charset=utf8', 'root','');
    // $val represent the id
    // $type represent the table (region / country)

    $return=True;   // set to true and later change to False is tests fail

    // Checking if there is any strategy for the region
    if ($type == 'region') {
        $strategy=$bdd->query("SELECT TOP 1 FROM market_strategy WHERE region_id='".$val."' ORDER BY name");
        if (!$data=$strategy->fetch()) { 
            $return=False; // there are no results
        }
    } elseif($type == 'country') { // Checking if there is any strategy for the country
        $strategy=$bdd->query("SELECT TOP 1 FROM market_strategy WHERE country_id='".$val."' ORDER BY name");
        if (!$data=$strategy->fetch()) {
            $return=False;    // there are no results
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Apologies in advance if any typos in code because I was not able to test.